# Get all columns after groupin and aggregating

Tags: azure-devops, odata

I am using this query

`https://{organization}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_odata/v2.0/WorkItemRevisions?$apply=groupby((WorkItemId), aggregate(Revision with max as Revision))`

to get the latest `Revision` for every `WorkItemId`. It does exactly what I want **but I also need all the other columns of the `WorkItemRevisions` table**. I have tried to use `$expand` but it did not work. Is there something I am missing?